# XPathExpression not evaluatng in the proper context?

Tags: java, android, xpath, evaluate

I'm trying to parse some XML from the USGS.

[Here's an example](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv?sites=07249455&parameterCd=00010,00060,00065&format=waterML,1.1)

The "parameterCd" parameter lists the 3 items of data I want back. I may or may not get all 3 back.

I'm doing this on an Android using the javax libraries.

In my code, I initially retrieve the 0-3 ns1:timeSeries nodes. This works fine. What I then want to do is, within the context of a single timeSeries node, retrieve the ns1:variable and ns1:values nodes.

So in my code below where I have:

```
expr = xpath.compile("//ns1:variable");
NodeList variableNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(timeSeriesNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I would expect to only get back one node, since the evaluate SHOULD be happening in the context of the single timeSeriesNode that I'm passing in (according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29)). Instead, however, it returns all of the ns1:variable nodes for the document, however.

Am I missing something?

Here's the relevant portions...

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new InstantaneousValuesNamespaceContext());
XPathExpression expr;
NodeList timeSeriesNodes = null;
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sourceXml.getBytes());
try {
    expr = xpath.compile("//ns1:timeSeries");
    timeSeriesNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(new InputSource(is), XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for(int timeSeriesIndex = 0;timeSeriesIndex < timeSeriesNodes.getLength(); timeSeriesIndex++){
        Node timeSeriesNode = timeSeriesNodes.item(timeSeriesIndex);
        expr = xpath.compile("//ns1:variable");
        NodeList variableNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(timeSeriesNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        // Problem here. I've got all the variables, not the individual one I want.
        for(int variableIndex = 0; variableIndex < variableNodes.getLength(); variableIndex++){
            Node variableNode = variableNodes.item(variableIndex);
            expr = xpath.compile("//ns1:valueType");
            NodeList valueTypeNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(variableNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        }
    }
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

```
//ns1:variable
```

to

```
.//ns1:variable
```

Even though, as the docs say, the expression is evaluated within the context of the current node, `//` is special and (unless modified) *always* means 'search the whole document from the root'. By putting the `.` in, you force the meaning you want, 'search the whole tree from this point downwards'.

Comment: Why does it work with a starting dot and not without the starting dot?

Comment: edit helps. From my point of view however, I find very *strange* the enforcing rule 'search the whole document from the root'.